# EF Core There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I am receiving **There is already an object named `AspNetRoles` in the database.** error while attempting to use `update-database` command in NuGet console.

Context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }


    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

Startup:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("DroneDeliveryWebApi")));

            // add identity
            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(o =>
            {
                // configure identity options
                o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                o.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                o.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            });
            builder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), builder.Services);
            builder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

appsetting.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DroneDeliverydb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "JwtIssuerOptions": {
      "Issuer": "DroneDeliveryWebApi",
      "Audience": "http://localhost:5000/"
    }
  }
}
```

appsetting.Development.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },

  "JwtIssuerOptions": {
    "Issuer": "DroneDeliveryWebApi",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:5000/"
  }
}
```

Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string IdentityId { get; set; }
    public AppUser Identity { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Locale { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Database:
[image]

Error:

```
PM> update-database
Applying migration '20190407181929_initial'.
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
    [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE [AspNetRoles] (
          [Id] nvarchar(450) NOT NULL,
          [ConcurrencyStamp] nvarchar(max) NULL,
          [Name] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          [NormalizedName] nvarchar(256) NULL,
          CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      );
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
ClientConnectionId:e40d4c0a-f6df-498d-a92b-06c3711b5106
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:e40d4c0a-f6df-498d-a92b-06c3711b5106
Error Number:2714,State:6,Class:16
There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
```

You can ask me for any additional information

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who struggle the same way as me.
The solution is to paste the **exact** Connection String of your database in appsettings.json and in appsettings.Development.json. Thus all authorization tables will be created.
[image]
**But** the error will keep appearing every time you run 'update-database' and no changes will be applied. Accordingly you can **comment** the **content of Up method** in the migration where all authorization tables are created.

```
 public partial class initial : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            //migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            //    name: "AspNetRoles",
            //    columns: table => new
            //    {
            //        Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
            //        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
            //        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
            //        NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
            //    },
            //    constraints: table =>
            //    {
            //        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
            //    });
            //
            //    ...
        }
    }
```

After these changes you will have the tables created and no errors will occur.

Comment: Except changes made to the models won't be applied to the database.

Comment: My problem was solved just by correcting my ConnectionString

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we have to drop the database anytime we see this error.

However, there is a way to keep the data while recreating the database:

Using SQL Server Management Studio, we can go to Task -> Generate Scripts, then 
in the "Set Scripting Options" window to back up the data, we should set the type of data to be backed up to "Data Only".

[image: Set the type of data to data only]

Then drop the database, issue Update-Database command, and restore the data by running the generated script;

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, I need to pull the changes from `github` but every time I add new migrations, I won't have the new changes given from github in my database! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70512142/not-considering-new-changes-when-adding-migrations-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Would you take a look at my question which I gave it's link to you abov?