# New Migration Failing with the 'Update-Database' command in Package Manager Console

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I am implementing a custom IdentityUser in my Asp.Net Core 2.2 Web App and I have added new properties to my IdentityUser and am trying to migrate it to my database in sql server so that the new properties are displayed correctly.

When I open package manager console and input: "Update-Database" I receive the: "There is already an object AspnetUsers is already in database".  I also tried naming/creating a new migration and then running the same "Update-Database" command but still receive the same error.

Here is a screenshot of the error output I received:
https://gyazo.com/e996af43b520ec7dc66dd16f9e79ba46

What I would like to happen would be for the migration to update my aspnetusers table to receive the new properties I inputted into my custom IdentityUser.

VisUser : IdentityUser

```
 public class VisUser : IdentityUser
    {


        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        public string VisUserName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        public string VisEmail { get; set; }

        public VisUser()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
```

dbcontext:

```
 public class dbContext : IdentityDbContext<VisUser>
    {
        public dbContext(DbContextOptions<dbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<VisUser> VisUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Up/Down method from 'init' migration

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoles", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                    EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
                    LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    FirstName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    MiddleInitial = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    LastName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    VisUserName = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    VisEmail = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetRoleClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ClaimType = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    ClaimValue = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserClaims", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ProviderKey = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ProviderDisplayName = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserLogins", x => new { x.LoginProvider, x.ProviderKey });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    RoleId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserRoles", x => new { x.UserId, x.RoleId });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
                        column: x => x.RoleId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetRoles",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    LoginProvider = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUserTokens", x => new { x.UserId, x.LoginProvider, x.Name });
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_AspNetUserTokens_AspNetUsers_UserId",
                        column: x => x.UserId,
                        principalTable: "AspNetUsers",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetRoleClaims_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetRoleClaims",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "RoleNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetRoles",
                column: "NormalizedName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserClaims_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserClaims",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserLogins_UserId",
                table: "AspNetUserLogins",
                column: "UserId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_AspNetUserRoles_RoleId",
                table: "AspNetUserRoles",
                column: "RoleId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "EmailIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedEmail");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "UserNameIndex",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                column: "NormalizedUserName",
                unique: true,
                filter: "[NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoleClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserClaims");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserLogins");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUserTokens");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetRoles");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "AspNetUsers");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete the database and migrations folder together, and then add migrations again?Could you tell us how to reproduce the problem?Aslo refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55562371/ef-core-there-is-already-an-object-named-aspnetroles-in-the-database

Comment: I deleted the migration folder in the Migration folder of my project and tried making a new Migration and calling "Update-Database" after but the Up and Down methods were blank and the database in my sql server remained unchanged.  Also, you said to delete the database that corresponds to this migration but wouldn't that delete the information and tables that are already there that do no correspond to the custom identity?

Comment: Yes,it will...But from the general error,it is hard to find the exact problem.I advice that you could give the reproduce steps and more related code.Or do you have errors when you try it in a new project?

Comment: I have added code for my VisUser ( :IdentityUser), dbcontext, and Up/Down methods from my 'init' migration.  I tried deleting the migrations from the migrations folder and adding new ones but the same error occurs.  This is the error when I run the application: https://gyazo.com/9f934c8fdf74d58f0d853f6ba40bdf5b .  I feel deleting the database and updating it again would fix this but I would like to find another way so I wouldn't have to do that in the future if this problem arises again.  Shouldn't down method drop remake the roles table? Let me know what pieces of code you would like to see.